# How to check the reason behind the property value becoming "null"

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005

I have a property like this

When I debugged I can see that `m_displayType` becoming `null`. Can anybody tell me how to check the reason behind it? I checked all the reference of `DisplayType` other than this any way I missed out.

Comment: Please make sure you tell us which line is becoming null. Is it in Type m_displayType line or is it in set or get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides debugging it and looking at the stack to see where the DisplayType is being called from, you need to make sure you are not changing the value using the m_displayType field instead of the property. You can do a find all references in VS on the m_displayType field and on the DisplayType property to see where they are used. Also, is there a reason why you are defining the m_displayType field as protected instead of private?

Comment: you are correct ,may be i need to check  m_displayType field as protected instead of private, but hwo to check that , let me try

Comment: There is no special check to see if it is protected. You can clearly see by the code above "protected Type m_displayType = typeof(ManagedDevice);" that it is protected. My question was why is it protected and not set as private? If your intention is to change the DisplayType value (from an inherited class) and not the ControlType, that would be the reason for having it as protected. In which case, you would have to check inherited classes that modify the m_displayType field.

Answer (score 2):

Put a breakpoint in the property setter and look at the call stack.

Comment: you meant put break point in the line if (m_displayType != value)  and check the call stack??

Answer (score 0):

you need to put a breakpoint in setter....that will gives the value whether it is null or not

Comment: i confirmed its null, i need to find the reason behind it ,thats my aim

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in the setter.  Go to the breakpoints window (Debug->Windows->Breakpoints). Right click on the breakpoint and select "Condition...".  Add "value==null" and leave "Is true" checked.

Answer (score 0):

Since `value` in the setter could be `null`, you might consider that you're setting it to null.

```
m_displayType != value
```

Considering the above line, if `value` is `null` and `m_displayType` is not, then the condition is met and `m_displayType = value` would be equivalent to `m_displayType = null`.

As for how to debug it, as others have said, set a breakpoint (select the appropriate line and press <kbd>F9</kbd>, I believe) - then run and step through the code, this will allow you to witness execution line by line and see exactly what *is* null and how it is being applied to `m_displayType`.

There is also the possibility that `m_displayType` is being set elsewhere: with it being protected this means that inheritors can manipulate the value directly, so did you find all references to the underlying variable of the property and check those accordingly?